# How to remove first word from folder name?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I have 26 folders with the names of my students (Firstname Lastname_somedata). Windows sorts this with their first name. I want to automate the deletion of their first name so their last last name comes first and sorts like it should.

Thanks!

Edit: An Example folder name "Anna Ansaleere_28032_assignsubmission_file_".
I have been trying some stuff but nothing that actually produced something usefull.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have already tried along with the specific issues/errors you are getting :)

Comment: Can you share what you've already attempted along with some data for us to look at?

Comment: What if two students share the same last name? Wouldn't it be better to swap the first- and last name and separate them with a comma or dash?

Comment: Do "somedata" contain a space character?

Comment: @Theo Yes, that would be even better if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, it would be better to have the first- and lastnames swapped with a comma in between. That way the possibility of ending up with duplicate folder names is rather unlikely.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\Test'
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $student, $remainder = $_.Name -split '_', 2
    # in case there is a folder where no space is found between the First and Last name
    if (!($student.Contains(' '))) {
        Write-Host "Not possible to find the First and Lastname in $($_.FullName)"
        continue
    }
    $firstname, $lastname = $student -split ' ', 2
    $newName = '{0}, {1}_{2}' -f $lastname, $firstname, $remainder
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
}
```

If you are satisfied with the resuts shown in the PowerShell console, remove the `-WhatIf` switch so the folders are actually renamed.

Before:

> ```
> Anna Ansaleere_28032_assignsubmission_file
> Henry This-Or-That_98765_assignsubmission_file
> John Doe_12345_rejection_file
> ```

After:

> ```
> Ansaleere, Anna_28032_assignsubmission_file_
> Doe, John_12345_rejection_file
> This-Or-That, Henry_98765_assignsubmission_file
> ```

<sup>P.S. if your version of PowerShell is less than 3.0, do `Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {..}` to return directories only</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! This is going to save a buttload of time and i'll share it with my colleagues! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that "somedata" do not contain a space (studentID parhaps?) this would work.

```
$folder_path = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\stackoverflow"
#Gets all folders from $folder_path location.
$folders = Get-ChildItem $folder_path | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    #Takes the second string after spliting it on "space" character.
    #In case of: Jonas Olsson_1452385
    #The second string would be: Olsson_1452385
    $new_name = ($folder.name).split(" ")[1]
    $new_name

    #Rename folder to new name
    Rename-Item $folder.FullName -NewName $new_name
}
```

PS, next time, let us know what you have tried when you post.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the help @David.

It worked for some folders but the rest didn't change and it spit out this error Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null.
At C:\Users\Dietr\Downloads\4a4\Script1.ps1:14 char:43
+     Rename-Item $folder.FullName -NewName $new_name
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Do you know which folder it stops working for? I would think that you get this error because the folder name is not in the same format, some folders is perhaps missing a space between firstname/lastname?